# Select column from relations relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to do eager loading using `with()` method, I only want to get selected column from relations relation, how can I do that ? . I'm using polymorphic relation.

```php
Draft::with(["user:id,username","article:id,locale","article.articleable:title"])->where([
            ["user_id",$user_id],
            ["is_suspended",1]
        ])->get();
```

**Draft Model**

```php
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Article");
}
```

**Article Model**

```php
public function drafts()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Draft", "article_id", "id");
}

public function articleable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**other models which has polymorphic relation with Article model**

```php
public function articles()
{
    return $this->morphMany("App\Models\Article", "articleable");
}
```

Comment: please add your migrations and models too, that would help

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, and it seems that because of the complexity, morph relationships are indifferent to the select statement. see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2966

Comment: @FatemehMajd so four years past away and still doesn't support :/

Comment: it's because it's not a technical issue, it's that when there is a morph relationship, select column does not make sense. there may be different columns on each morph model

Comment: @FatemehMajd all morph models have some clumns named same like title slug

Comment: With a polymorphic relationship you can't know what to load without first loading up the column with the relation type.  Eloquent may understand that the type column corresponds to another table in the db but mysql (or whatever db you're using) does not.  This is why it's not logical to ask for a polymorphic relation in a "with()" call.

Comment: @HasanTıngıryes you are right for your case, but in general, it can not be sure. look at the point that mattQuest makes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in Laravel 5.7.6: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25662

In order for this to work, you also have to select the `id` column:

```php
Draft::with('user:id,username', 'article:id,locale', 'article.articleable:id,title')
                                                                          ^^
    ->where([
        ['user_id', $user_id],
        ['is_suspended', 1]
    ])->get();
```

Comment: I should check new commits .. :/